# python3 subprocess stuck in docker alpine container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, subprocess, alpine-linux

I have a python3.7 alpine image(python:3.7.7-alpine3.10).

when i run code blow in the container:

```
import io
import time
import subprocess
import sys

filename = '/tmp/test.log'
with io.open(filename, 'wb') as writer, io.open(filename, 'rb', 1) as reader:
    process = subprocess.Popen("ping google.com", stdout=writer, shell=True)
    while process.poll() is None:
        sys.stdout.write(reader.read().decode("utf-8"))
        time.sleep(0.5)
    # Read the remaining
    sys.stdout.write(reader.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

it only output and write the first line:

```
PING google.com (172.217.160.110): 56 data bytes
```

then nothing else and the process stucks.

it should keep output to stdout and writing into file `/tmp/test.log` which works on my mac host

I run contaniner with `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined` and strace the process in it, it seems show that the `ping` is working correctly, keeps ping

```
strace: Process 6 attached
recvfrom(0, 0x55ef843c29a0, 192, 0, 0x7ffdb0da2200, [16]) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=1328545, tv_nsec=930698343}) = 0
sendto(0, "\10\0\245d\6\0\0*\312\35\202S\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 64, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.217.160.110")}, 28) = 64
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55ef84325e4f, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f479076de21}, {sa_handler=0x55ef84325e4f, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f479076de21}, 8) = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}, it_value={tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}}, NULL) = 0
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 45
recvfrom(0, 0x55ef843c29a0, 192, 0, 0x7ffdb0da2200, [16]) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGALRM {si_signo=SIGALRM, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {tv_sec=1328546, tv_nsec=934499243}) = 0
sendto(0, "\10\0}\22\6\0\0+\343n\221S\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 64, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.217.160.110")}, 28) = 64
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55ef84325e4f, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f479076de21}, {sa_handler=0x55ef84325e4f, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f479076de21}, 8) = 0
setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, {it_interval={tv_sec=0, tv_usec=0}, it_value={tv_sec=1, tv_usec=0}}, NULL) = 0
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 45
recvfrom(0, ^Cstrace: Process 6 detached
 <detached ...>
```

But the code just works fine in my mac host.

I have tried a lot times and it will always stucks which is so noisy

Hope anyone helps, Thanks

-----------------------------------Update 2020.4.22 11:19-------

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.7-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /app
COPY test.py .

RUN python test.py # RUN this test when exec "docker build"
```

test.py contains the code above

Or you can just copy the code to `test.py` and run like this

```
docker run  -v `pwd`:/tmp --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined python:3.7.7-alpine3.10 python3 /tmp/test.py
```

I also try the code below

```
import io
import time
import subprocess
import sys

process = subprocess.Popen("ping google.com", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,  shell=True)
while process.poll() is None:
    print("--" * 10)
    print(process.stdout.readline())
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

But it just ouput nothing

Comment: I just tested your code and it works. Can you please share how you start the container and run the code ?

Comment: My guess would be that `reader` is at end-of-file after its first read.  Can you use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to avoid the temporary file here?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanx for your reply. I tried you suggestion, you can check the question and i have updated with your suggestion, but it still not work